# catch block not covered in unit testing

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, exception, junit

I have written a test case for the exception is passed but does not cover code coverage.

Please help me I tried many ways but doesn't resolve.

```
public String checkJiraStatus(HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection) throws IOException {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(stringBuilder));
        JSONObject fields = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("fields");
        JSONObject status = (JSONObject) fields.get("status");
        return (String) status.get("name");
    }catch (IOException |JSONException ioException) {
        throw new IOException("Problem while fetching the data"+ioException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

test case passes correctly but didn't give code coverage.

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void testIoException() throws Exception {
    when(mockJiraFunctions.checkJiraStatus(any())).thenThrow(new 
            IOException("Problem while fetching the data"));
    jiraFunctions.checkJiraStatus(any());
}
```

Comment: It's because in your test you throw exception from a mock object instead of calling a real method.

Comment: This is a _great_ reason to refactor your code to pass in a `Reader` or `InputStream` directly to the code under test, so you can feed it invalid JSON.

Comment: @Ruslan            @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void testIoException() throws Exception {
 jiraFunctions.checkJiraStatus(any());
    }       **I try this also it doesn't work.**

Comment: @NikitaKushwah, what is **any()** in your code? It's your function, which you haven't posted, or you try to run your real method with Mockito.any() as argument?

Comment: yes, Mockito.any() as argument @Ruslan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, you should run your real method to have a coverage.
And you should make a situation, where your function will throw an exception. For example in your case you can make a mock object of HttpURLConnection class and make him throw IOException when you call getInputStream() method on it.

So your test will be like

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void test() {
    HttpURLConnection connectionMock = mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
    when(connectionMock.getInputStream()).thenThrow(new IOException());
    jiraFunctions.checkJiraStatus(connectionMock);
}
```