# catch not covered in code coverage exception test case

Tags: java, exception, junit

I tried soo many ways and now finally my test case gets a pass but it doesn't cover in code coverage.

```
public int createBranch (String userName, String password, String gitRepo, String jiraNumber, String shaOfMaster) throws
        IOException {
            String baseUrl = "https://github.abc.com/api/v3/repos/";
            String logicUrl = "/git/refs";
            String gitUrl = baseUrl + gitRepo + logicUrl;
            String refs = "refs/heads/" + jiraNumber;
            try {
                URL urlObject = new URL(gitUrl);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                String auth = userName + ":" + password;
                byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                String authHeaderValue = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeaderValue);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                String postJsonData = "{\n" +
                        "    \"ref\":\"" + refs +
                        "\",\n" +
                        "    \"sha\":\"" + shaOfMaster +
                        "\"\n" +
                        "}";
                wr.writeBytes(postJsonData);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                return httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                throw new IOException("connection Not Found" + exception.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

**the test case  I have written**

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void testExceptionForCreateBranch() throws Exception {
       when(mockGitHubFunctions.createBranch(anyString(),anyString(),anyString(),anyString(),anyString())).thenThrow(IOException.class);
        assertThrows(IOException.class, ()-> mockGitHubFunctions.createBranch(anyString(),anyString(),anyString(),anyString()));
    }
```

please help me to resolve these problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [catch block not covered in unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68086746/catch-block-not-covered-in-unit-testing)

Comment: @Ruslan I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: `assertThrows(IOException.class, ()-> mockGitHubFunctions.deleteBranch(......` you're not testing the method you're showing us

Comment: About your edit, now the problem is *exactly* what the linked answer says it is: you're running a mocked method, not your actual method, so you're not actually testing it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I made mistake to write here I edited it.

Comment: gitHubFunctions.createBranch(anyString(),anyString(),anyString(),anyString(),anyString());  when i am using this way it gives me error java assertionError Expected  exception @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: @Ruslan now I am using the actual method                                                                   
    ```` gitHubFunctions.createBranch(anyString(),anyString(),anyString(),anyString(),anyString());````                                                                                                                             
 but still its not working please help in this.

Comment: @ShikharKushwah Yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about. You don't need to mock gitHubFunctions object when you trying to test it. So you don't need mockGitHubFunctions object at all. I already linked absolutely the same question in my first comment.

Comment: @Ruslan now i am not using mock object but now problem is it giving me error java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.Exception